# "Microsoft Internet Controls" reference sometimes requires re-assignation

Tags: vba

Every once in a while, on my same PC or on new PC with the same Windows (7) version and Excel (2010) version, when I try my usual Excel file with a VBA using "Microsoft Internet Controls" reference, debug incorrectly fails with a "Compile error: can't assign to array".
I found that the problem is immediately fixed by just re-assigning the "Microsoft Internet Controls" (uncheck-OK, then again check-OK).
Note: its path is "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ieframe.dll".

It's like if my functions which use that "Microsoft Internet Controls" library, and I designed to return an array, stop to work because the link to "Microsoft Internet Controls" gets corrupted(??!).

I'm really lost on this.
Any ideas about how this problem can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved adding a call to this sub from ThisWorkbook:

```
Sub Readd_Reference_Microsoft_Internet_Controls()
    Const fullpath = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ieframe.dll"
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove GetReferenceFromPath(fullpath)

    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile fullpath
    'ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{EAB22AC0-30C1-11CF-A7EB-0000C05BAE0B}", 0, 0 'Microsoft Internet Controls
End Sub

Private Function GetReferenceFromPath(ByVal strSearchFullPath As String) As Object
    Dim oFs As FileSystemObject, oReferenceS As References, oReference As Reference, sRefFileName As String

    Set oFs = New FileSystemObject

    Dim sSearchFileName As String
    sSearchFileName = oFs.GetFileName(strSearchFullPath)
    Set oReferenceS = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References
    For Each oReference In oReferenceS
        sRefFileName = oFs.GetFileName(oReference.fullpath)
        If StrComp(sSearchFileName, sRefFileName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' se uguale
            Set GetReferenceFromPath = oReference
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```